# Pictures saved to computer without owners knowledge and/or use of comp in a week

Tags: file-system

How can images be saved to someone's computer - in their pictures folder - without the owner's knowledge or use of the computer in over a week?

I cannot find anything about this happening anywhere or how it could happen. The only people who have access are me and my fiancee, and I don't use his computer since I have my own. So, how is it that an image can be saved into the pictures folder on the computer without my fiancee knowing about it?

Comment: Right click on the picture(s) in question and look at the file creation date, then ask some questions about what was going on at that time. I have a feeling you're being misled.

Comment: I right clicked, and checked that. I also looked over the downloads. Found a similar image that was removed not too long before I seen that other image and not long before the creation date. I did ask questions, and he got defensive. :\

Answer (score 2):

A simple explanation is that a cloud backup app is set up on the PC and will sync files which are loaded to the cloud (such as dropbox, box, onedrive, google drive, etcetc) by also copying files down to the PC.  If you want a more detailed answer you are going to have to provide more info, though.  Was the PC turned on or off? Why do you suspect it wasn't him? What is the source of the proof that the files were placed without his intervention?

Comment: The PC was turned on. I didn't say I don't suspect it wasn't him, honestly that's the reason I am asking, is because I do suspect it was him. He has no proof. I check the downloads for his computer, and there was a similar image that was removed a few days prior to me finding this other one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to cloud services, some programs like Adobe Lightroom will attempt to download pictures from literally any device you plug into the computer (USB drive, SD card, Android phones, possibly iPod?). It's quite annoying, and someone not paying attention could blindly click "yes" to the prompts.

You don't mention the nature of the pictures but I'm guessing they're not vacation photos of the two of you, so I don't see this as being a likely scenario.

Comment: Hahah, between the lines this question is "my fiancée is denying he ever saw these photos that I found on his computer. Is he lying, or just full of it?"

Comment: Agreed. Hilariously, I once discovered some peculiar results in my own web history so I asked a similar question-- "Have I been compromised?" Responders accused me of trying to find technical excuses to cover my own tracks, but upon confrontation the culprit turned out to be my wife-- the last person I'd ever suspect!

Comment: Thank is what I am asking, @Jeff. Failed at being more discrete about it lol.

Comment: And yes @Ivan, the picture I found was... well, it was basically an advertisement that was saved as a picture for an adult content website. Something my fiancee states he never looks at while in a relationship. (This isn't the first time this has happened). He told me to google, couldn't find any explanation, so I figured I should ask here.